# MariaDB 10.9.3: MySQL query takes way to much time. How to refactor this?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a database that contains two tables: articles with core data and articleHistory with delivered articles, its corresponding prices and amounts. To calculate the real price based on deliveries and not the average price in the base information, i need to query all articles and add the history, containing only enough results to match at least the amount in the inventory.

Currently i'm using two separate querys. First i gather all articles and then, in a for loop, i try to add the history information to calculate the price in php later on:

```
-- First get all articles:
SELECT Artikel.Artikel,
       Artikel.Hersteller,
       Artikel.Bezeichnung1,
       Artikel.Bezeichnung2,
       Artikel.Matchcode,
       Artikel.Stellplatzname,
       Artikel.BestandAktuell,
       Artikel.Nachkommastellen
FROM artikel AS Artikel;

-- Use for loop to get history into nested array:
SELECT t.Menge,
       t.Preiseinheit,
       t.Einheitspreis,
       t.Datum,
       @total := @total + t.Menge AS Summe
FROM (SELECT *, @total := 0 FROM artikelhistorie WHERE Vorgang = 'EL' AND Header_Artikel = '$Artikel' AND Header_Hersteller = '$Hersteller' ORDER BY Datum DESC) t
WHERE t.Vorgang = 'EL'
AND t.Header_Artikel = '$Artikel'
AND t.Header_Hersteller = '$Hersteller'
AND @total < $Bestand;
```

But this query takes more than 2 seconds per article and with more than 5000 articles in the database, it takes way to much time (>2,5hours). How can i refactor this query or use a complete different one to speed up the task? Is there a way to use only one query and calculate the amount right away?
I'm not up to the task in MySQL itself so i'm currently using PHP to complete this task.

The two tables have the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `artikel` (
  `Artikel` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `Hersteller` char(10) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `Bezeichnung1` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Bezeichnung2` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Gewicht` decimal(9,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `ArtikelhistorieAnker` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `RabattierungsKz` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `USt_Satz_Alt` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `Artikelgruppe` char(3) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '999',
  `Erloescode` char(2) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '01',
  `Mengeneinheit` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Preiseinheit` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Preiserrechnungsformel` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Eingabefolge` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Nachkommastellen` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Provisionssatz` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Bewertungssatz` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `RabattstaffelVerkauf` char(2) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '00',
  `RabattgruppeVerkauf` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Aktionscode` char(2) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '00',
  `VerbrauchPeriode` decimal(15,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `VerbrauchKumuliert` decimal(15,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `UmsatzPeriode` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `UmsatzKumuliert` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `RoherloesPeriode` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `RoherloesKumuliert` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `BestandAktuell` decimal(15,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `FertigungsKz` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Sonderpreis` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `SonderpreisGueltigBis` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0100-01-01',
  `Frei` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Verkaufspreis1` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Verkaufspreis2` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Verkaufspreis3` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `ArtikelzusatztextAnker` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LizenzkennzeichenAlt` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Frei1` varbinary(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Stellplatzname` varchar(6) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `MittlererEinkaufspreis` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `LizenzkennzeichenNeu` varchar(8) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Frei2` varbinary(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Bestellkennzeichen` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Gebindefaktor` decimal(9,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `Mindest_Meldebestand` decimal(15,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ProvisionierungsKz` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `Matchcode` varchar(40) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ArtikeltextSprache1Anker` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ArtikeltextSprache2Anker` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ArtikeltextSprache3Anker` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `FesterLieferant` char(10) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000000000',
  `TextergaenzungsKz` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LagerfuehrungsKz` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `HistorieneintragsKz` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Lizenzkennzeichen` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `Anker_Dokumente` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Ende_Dokumente` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Frei3` varchar(5) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Prueflizenzgruppe` varchar(8) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Gewichtseinheit` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `KalkulatorischerEinkaufspreis` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Bezugskostenzuschlag_Alt` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Gemeinkostenzuschlag_Alt` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Gewinnzuschlag_Alt` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `KalkulatorischerEK_PflegeKz` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `Kostentraegernummer` char(10) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Umrechnungsfaktor` decimal(15,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000',
  `UmrechnungsfaktorMengeneinheit` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `UmrechnungsfaktorMengenformat` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `UmrechnungsfaktorEingabefolge` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SteuerklassenzugriffsKz` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ArtikeltextSprache4Anker` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ArtikeltextSprache5Anker` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ArtikeltextSprache6Anker` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ArtikeltextSprache7Anker` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ArtikeltextSprache8Anker` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ArtikeltextSprache9Anker` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Steuerklasse` char(3) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '001',
  `SonderpreisGueltigAb` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0100-01-01',
  `Standardlager` char(4) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0001',
  `Verkaufspreis4` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Verkaufspreis5` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Verkaufspreis6` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Verkaufspreis7` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Verkaufspreis8` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Verkaufspreis9` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Dispokennzeichen` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `MaterialgemeinkostenNr` char(3) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '000',
  `VerwaltungsgemeinkostenNr` char(3) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '000',
  `VertriebsgemeinkostenNr` char(3) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '000',
  `GewinnzuschlagNr` char(3) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '000',
  `EntwicklungsgemeinkostenNr` char(3) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '000',
  `VerkaufspreiskalkulationsKz` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Frei4` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Frei31` varchar(3) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Statuskennzeichen` varchar(2) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Verkaufskennzeichen` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `Chargenpflichtkennzeichen` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Chargenentnahmekennzeichen` varchar(2) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'E1',
  `ChargenVorlauftage` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ChargenAblaufzeit` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ChargenSperrkennzeichen` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'F',
  `ChargenNummernkreistyp` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'S',
  `ChargenNummernkreis` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '00000000000000000000',
  `ChargennummerVergabeKz` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `ChargennummerZeichenvorrat` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'G',
  `ChargenBelegdruckkennzeichen` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '4',
  `Lieferantenchargekenzeichen` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'J',
  `Chargenposition_Initial_Anker` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `StandardlagerEinkauf` char(4) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0001',
  `Frei41` varchar(30) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Frei5` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Timestamp_Datum` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0100-01-01',
  `Timestamp_Zeit` time NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00',
  `Timestamp_Benutzer` varchar(3) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `LetzteLieferung` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0100-01-01',
  `Sperrvermerk1` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Sperrvermerk2` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Sperrvermerk3` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Sperrvermerk4` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Sperrvermerk5` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Sperrvermerk6` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Anker_Memo` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `MaterialGKPreset` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `VerwaltungsGKPreset` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `VertriebsGKPreset` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '3',
  `GewinnzuschlagPreset` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '4',
  `EntwicklungsGKPreset` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '5',
  `MengeneinheitPreset` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '6',
  `USER_ECCN` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `USER_EUECCN` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `USER_Herkunftsland` varchar(3) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `USER_Zolltarifnummer` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `USER_SVHC` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Artikel`,`Hersteller`),
  KEY `ZZ_ArtikelIndexTimestamp` (`Timestamp_Datum`,`Timestamp_Zeit`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `artikelhistorie` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ChainGuid` char(36) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `Sequence` decimal(38,0) NOT NULL,
  `Guid` char(36) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `Header_Artikel` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Header_Hersteller` char(10) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Positionstyp` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `Datum` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0100-01-01',
  `Vorgang` varchar(2) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Nummer` varchar(11) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Kunde` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Menge` decimal(15,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Einheitspreis` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Rabatte` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Roherloes` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Kundenkurzbezeichnung` varchar(28) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Positionsart` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Wareneingangsnr_GemaessBW` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `KzAnzeigeWareneingangsNr` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Preiseinheit` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Auftrags_Bestellnummer` varchar(11) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Auftrags_Bestelldatum` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0100-01-01',
  `CheckIntern` varchar(5) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Kostenstelle` char(10) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Reserviert2` varchar(5) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Kostentraeger` char(10) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Stuecklisten_Pos_KZ` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Art` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Seriennummer` varchar(30) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Text` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `ZZ_ChainIndex` (`ChainGuid`,`Sequence`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;
```

The PHP code is straightforward:

```
$sage = new TBSageConnector();

// executes the first query
$artikel = $sage->holeAlleArtikel();

// executes the second query in a loop
for($i=0;$i<count($artikel);$i++) {
    $art = $artikel[$i]['Artikel'];
    $her = $artikel[$i]['Hersteller'];
    $bes = $artikel[$i]['Bestand'];
    $artikel[$i]['Historie'] = $sage->holeArtikelHistorieBisBestand($art, $her, $bes);
}
```

I'm using MariaDB 10.9.3 and PHP8.

Output of EXPLAIN on the first query:

```
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | extra |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Artikel | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 6318 |       |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
```

Output of EXPLAIN on the second query:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | extra                       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>      | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 315324 | Using where                 |
|  2 | DERIVED     | artikelhistorie | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 315324 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: What does the execution plan tell you? Without any details about the table structure, it's close to impossible to provide specific answers

Comment: And you should include the mysql version information, too.

Comment: Basically there's too much information missing from your question to join the two queries. The PHP loop is missing, and I cannot figure out where results from the first query are used in the second.

Comment: You still forgot to share the execution plan for that query

Comment: I added the requested information to the question! Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: @NicoHaase What do you mean with the execution plan? There are thousands of articles in the article table and the core information only contains an average price per article. I'd like to get the real price, that is a based on the history of deliveries.
Please tell me if i'm missing something here. Trying for quite some time...

Comment: I think Nico Haase is referring to [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html)? He didn't explain that very well, now did he? 

Comment: Learned something new here, thank you. I really don't know how to interpret this... yet. I'm going to add this to the question anyways :D

Comment: Yes, EXPLAIN needs some getting used to. It seems like you did an EXPLAIN on the second query in your question. It tells us there are no [indexes in your tables](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index/). You might want to add those, they can speed up queries enormously.

Comment: Well, i feel somewhat stupid now :) Adding indexes did the trick. The query is down to .01 seconds...

Comment: Nice. Now try the JOIN proposed by Ananth MK. If it doesn't work let him know. A join is much better than endlessly repeating the second query.

Answer (score 0):

Try joining your article and history tables by Left outer join using the join predicates.  Find the SUM inside subquery. Then apply your condition to filter records which satisfies the amount in inventory. I come up with the below query, please try(not tested).

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT Artikel.Artikel,
           Artikel.Hersteller,
           Artikel.Bezeichnung1,
           Artikel.Bezeichnung2,
           Artikel.Matchcode,
           Artikel.Stellplatzname,
           Artikel.BestandAktuell,
           Artikel.Nachkommastellen,
           History.Menge,
           History.Preiseinheit,
           History.Einheitspreis,
           History.Datum,
           (SELECT SUM(H.Menge) FROM artikelhistorie AS H WHERE H.Header_Artikel = History.Header_Artikel AND H.Header_Hersteller = History.Header_Hersteller AND H.Vorgang = 'EL') AS Summe       
    FROM artikel AS Artikel
    LEFT JOIN artikelhistorie AS History ON Artikel.Artikel = History.Header_Artikel AND 
        Artikel.Hersteller = History.Header_Hersteller AND History.Vorgang = 'EL'
) Overall
WHERE Summe < AmountInInventory;
```